# How angular momentum conservation is related to the isotropy of space?

Tags: angular-momentum, space

In Landau & Lifshitz Vol. 3 Section 54 "Spin" they say:

> In both classical and quantum mechanics, the law of conservation of
>   angular momentum is a consequence of the isotropy of space with
>   respect to a closed system.

1. What is the meaning of "with respect to a closed system"?
2. How angular momentum is a consequence of space isotropy?

Comment: Look into Noether's Theorem.